# React render array of images in array

Tags: reactjs

end app for woocommerce store, but i have problem  rendering the first image of array in 
when i console.log(images.src) i see the list of urls of the images, but in img src= it return : TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of undefined
I will be very thankful to help me correctly map the images.
here is my code:

```
class App extends React.Component  {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.getPosts = this.getPosts.bind(this);
    this.state = {
    posts : [],
    images: []
    };
  }
  getPosts = async () => {
    let res = await api.get("products", {
      per_page: 20,
    })

    let { data } = await res;
    this.setState({ posts: data });
  }

 componentDidMount = async () => {
  await this.getPosts();
};
 render() {
  const { posts } = this.state;
  const { images } = this.state
  return(
    <div>
   <Head>
      <title>Онлайн магазин KIKI.BG</title>
      <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />

 </Head>

 <React.Fragment >
                {posts.map((posts, index ) => {
                  { 
                    posts.images.map((images, subindex) =>

                  console.log(images.src),
                    <img src={images[0].src} />
                    )}
                    return (
                      <div>
                <h1>{posts.name}</h1>
                <h2>{posts.price}</h2>
                             </div>  
                             )})}
          </React.Fragment>

 </div>
  )
}
  }
  export default App;
```

Comment: I think You should remove the `console.log(images.src)` from the posts.images.map(). It will map your array to an undefined array  :)

Comment: post the posts.images what does it contain inside

Comment: Yes, i just test if image url endpoints are logged,  and console.log return the correct  endpoints for example https://xxxxxx/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/570-496-max.jpg , but <img src={images[0].src} /> return TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

```
            {posts.map((posts, index ) => {
              { 
                posts.images.src.map((image, subindex) =>

                <img src={image.src} />
                )}
                return (
                  <div>
                       <h1>{posts.name}</h1>
                       <h2>{posts.price}</h2>
                 </div>  
                )
              })}
```

Comment: it return <img src="[object Object]">

Comment: do a console log of image   and  post it here

Comment: the response is:   index.js:50 
{id: 177401, date_created: "2019-12-02T14:41:29", date_created_gmt: "2019-12-02T10:41:29", date_modified: "2019-12-02T14:41:29", date_modified_gmt: "2019-12-02T10:41:29", …}
alt: ""
date_created: "2019-12-02T14:41:29"
date_created_gmt: "2019-12-02T10:41:29"
date_modified: "2019-12-02T14:41:29"
date_modified_gmt: "2019-12-02T10:41:29"
id: 177401
name: "570-570-max"
src: "https://kiki.bg/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/570-570-max.jpg"
__proto__: Object

Comment: it returns TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: do this:      console.log(JSON.stringify(posts.images)) and post everything in here (i mean from start to end)

Comment: i found solution i fixed it as following : {posts.map((posts, index ) => {
   console.log(posts.images)
              return (
                      <div key={{index}}>
          {posts.images.map((image,i ) => 
          <img key={{i}} src={image.src} />
          )}
                 <h1>{posts.name}</h1>
           
                <h2>{posts.price}</h2>
                             </div>  
                             )})}

Answer (score 0):

well, `console.log(images.src) i see the list of urls of the images` doesn't make any sense.. `images` is array. So `images[0]` should be image with data with property `src` on it?. Btw a lot of stuff in this code is just wrong.

- Don't rebind `getPosts` already bound `getPosts` function in constructor (via class property) (getPosts). BTW you dont need to bind is here at all, its not called as a callback.
- Its weird, that you call `await res` after `api.get()` ... shouldn't be it just `await api.get()`? Another `await` is usually used on fetch, when you do something like `await response.json()`.
- There is no need for async/await in componentDidMount
- If getPosts will throw it will mess up your component, its better to handle error in catch and call props.onError(error) for example
- You don't have any `key` attributes on element in map, thats wrong. You should put some unique id there (url fe? if not same, or id) for proper component re-render.
- You have some weird brackets issue in your maps...
- You shouldn't use more than one h1 one the page :-)
- images.src should be string, not array...
- Why is there subindex and index when u are not using it?
- Why you store images when they are not filled anywhere? Are they in the response of get? Thats maybe why u get an TypeError !
- I would add loading and no data message...

That would be my code:

```js
import { Component, Fragment } from 'react';

class App extends Component {

  static defaultProps = {
    onError: console.error;
  };

  state = {
    posts: [],
    images: [],
    loading: false,
  };

  // This could be done with hooks much better tho...
  async componentDidMount () {
     this.setState({ loading: true });

     try {      
       await this._fetchData();
     }
     catch (error) {
       this.props.onError(error); // Or something rendered in state.error?
     }
     finally {
       this.setState({ loading: false });
     }
  }

  render () {
    const { images, posts, loading } = this.state;

    if (!images.length) {
      return <div>No data.</div>;
    }

    if (loading) {
      return <div>Loading</div>;
    }

    const postBoxes = posts.map((post, index) => {
      const image = images[index];
      // Because you don't know, if that specific image is there... if this are your data..
      const imageElement = image ? 
         <img src={image.src} alt="dont know" /> :
         null;
      const { name, price } = post;

      // If name is unique, otherwise some id.
      return (
        <Fragment key={name} >
          {imageElement}

          <h2>{name}</h2>
          <h3>{price}</h3>            
        </Fragment>
      );      
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <Head>
          <title>Онлайн магазин KIKI.BG</title>
          <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
        </Head>

        <Fragment>
          {postBoxes}
        </Fragment>
      </div>
    );
  }

  async _fetchData () {
    const { data } = await api.get('products', { per_page: 20 });

    const { posts, images } = data;

    this.setState({ posts, images });
  }
}


export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

if `console.log(images.src)` -> gives list of images.

Then,

`<img src={images.src[0]}/>` -> should do the trick.

may be, Add a null check to be certain.

```
  images.src[0] && <img src={images.src[0]}/>
```